# After button click move from array index 0 to 1 and so on

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uikit

I've an array of struct, after clicking the correct answer( code below ) I want to change the array index from `questions[0]` to `questions[1]`, I meant to move through arrays. is it possible in any simple ways ?

any solution will be appericated

```swift
    var questions:[EasyQuestions] = [
        EasyQuestions(question: "1 + 1", optionA: "5", optionB: "2", hint: "3-1", correctAnswer: 1),
        EasyQuestions(question: "2 + 2", optionA: "4", optionB: "3", hint: "5-1", correctAnswer: 0)
    ].shuffled()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configure(with: questions[0])
    }
        @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == questions[0].correctAnswer {
            print("The answer is correct") // after printing this I want to move on the next element of questions array
        }
    }
    
    func configure(with question: EasyQuestions){
        self.Question.text = question.question
        self.button1.setTitle(question.optionA, for: .normal)
        self.button2.setTitle(question.optionB, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: Save question index in an instance variable. Increment by one if correct answer then load question at question index.

Comment: @PtitXav I tried that "hack" but the `configure` function doesn't work. the text of `question` `button1` and `button2` are still the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
var currentIndex = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configure()
}
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == questions[currentIndex].correctAnswer {
        print("The answer is correct")
        configure()
    }
}
func configure(){
    if currentIndex < questions.count {
        let question = questions[currentIndex]
        self.question.text = question.question
        self.button1.setTitle(question.optionA, for: .normal)
        self.button2.setTitle(question.optionB, for: .normal) 
        currentIndex += 1
    }

}
```

> make sure to set tags of button1 and button2 to 0,1 respectively

Comment: I copied your code but after clicking the correct answer button label, button1 and button2 don't change

Comment: Make sure that you connect both buttons to the action method with correct tags also add breakpoints inside it to track your code execution